# How to get rid of Autofac error?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

We have ASP.NET application where we use Autofac. The following error comes up:

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ConcertRu.ApplicationsCore.Services.SessionWebAppService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.HttpContext httpContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.HttpContext)'.
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.HttpContextBase)'.
Cannot resolve parameter 'ConcertRu.Infrastructure.Contracts.IConcertHttpContext httpContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(ConcertRu.Model.Contracts.IConcertDb, ConcertRu.Infrastructure.Contracts.IConcertHttpContext)'.
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
// Create the container builder.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the Web API controllers.
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Register other dependencies.
var services = typeof(AccessTokenService).Assembly;
builder.Register(c => ConcertDb.Current).As<IConcertDb>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

// Build the container.
var container = builder.Build();

// Create the depenedency resolver.
var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

// Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
```

The SessionWebAppService class:

```
public class SessionWebAppService : WebAppServiceBase, ISessionWebAppService
{
    public SessionWebAppService(HttpContext httpContext)
        : this(new ConcertDb(), new WebFormContext(httpContext))
    {
    }

    public SessionWebAppService(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        : this(new ConcertDb(), new MvcContext(httpContext))
    {
    }

    public SessionWebAppService(IConcertDb concertDb, IConcertHttpContext httpContext)
        : base(concertDb, httpContext)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

The WebAppServiceBase class:

```
public abstract class WebAppServiceBase : ModelServiceBase
{
    private readonly IConcertHttpContext _httpContext;

    protected WebAppServiceBase(IConcertDb concertDb, IConcertHttpContext httpContext) : base(concertDb)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac states quite clearly what is wrong: neither `HttpContext`, `HttpContextBase` or `IConcertHttpContext` can be resolved from the container. Seeing your registration code, this makes sense because only controllers, your `IConcertDb` an services are registered.

Comment: I've already tried to register those components, but new errors come up.

Comment: My question is - what to begin with?

Comment: You asked this same question [on the discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autofac/WBJIRY5QsB0) and we told you the same thing - if you're not registering the thing it's asking for, you need to register it. If you get new errors after that, what are they? You could be missing more than just the one registration.

Comment: I additionally did this:

builder.RegisterType<HttpContext>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>().SingleInstance();

And got the following error:

Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'ConcertRu.ApplicationsCore.Services.SessionWebAppService'. Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.

What to do next?

Comment: @tesicg - there are two issues here. 1) read the Autofac error and think! I will let it be an exercise for you to figure out what to do. 2) you cannot register `HttpContext/HttpContextBase` as a type. This implies that Autofac should create those objects. Will Autofac be able to? No, they are owned and produced by ASP.NET! You can, however, register a delegate that fetches the context from the current request. Again, I'm tempted to let you try and figure out how yourself.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I did this:

builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerDependency();

And there's no more error, but I'm not sure if this is right approach.

Comment: @tesicg - sure, thats a good approach. I hope you lifted that from the answer to your other SO question :) You could optimize it a bit, and register it as `InstancePerRequest` since the http context will be the same for the whole request, so there is no need to (potentially) create multiple `HttpContextWrappers` within a request.

Comment: @tesicg - I encourage you to try and learn/understand what is going on here. These mechanisms are what makes DI in general, and Autofac specifically, so powerful.